# Manually hide ng2-bootstrap pop-over

Tags: angular, popover, bootstrap-popover

```
<template #popDefinitionsTemplate>
    <h4>{{definitions.title}}</h4>
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    <hr>
    <div [innerHtml]="getDefinitionsPopoverContent()"></div>
</template>
<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-finish-later pull-right" 
        [popover]="popDefinitionsTemplate"
        placement="bottom">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> 
</button>
```

I have this code for displaying popover in my page. I want to include a manual hiding on the close button beside the title, something like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-times" (click)="popover.hide()"></i>
```

I'm not quite sure how to implement this one.

Note that this is from https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover#popover-config

Comment: Could you move the solution to an answer? Easier to find for anyone stumbling upon this in the future. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: thanks @MatthiasMeid. doing it now. :D

Comment: ... and don't forget to accept the answer as @a_horse_with_no_name suggested. ;)

Comment: I've got to wait 2 days (after posting the question) before accepting it as answer :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now working:

```
<template #popDefinitionsTemplate>
    <h4>{{definitions.title}}</h4>
    <i class="fa fa-times" (click)="popDefinitions.hide()"></i>
    <hr>
    <div [innerHtml]="getDefinitionsPopoverContent()"></div>
</template>
<button #popDefinitions="bs-popover" class="btn btn-secondary btn-finish-later pull-right" 
        [popover]="popDefinitionsTemplate"
        placement="bottom">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> 
</button>
```

Good thing I've stumbled upon this thread: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/1477